# What is the location of file that is read?

Tags: java

Im testing an example code which shows the use of exceptions management, and it uses a text file as example.

My problem is that i don't know where is the default location of that archive to create it.

This is the code:

```java
package exceptionManager;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
public class CheckedExceptionDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Below line calls readFile method and prints content of it
        String filename="test.txt";
        try {
            String fileContent = new CheckedExceptionDemo().readFile(filename);
            System.out.println(fileContent);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File:"+ filename+" is missing, Please check file name");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("File is not having permission to read, please check the permission");
        }
    }
    public String readFile(String filename)throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        FileInputStream fin;
        int i;
        String s="";
        fin = new FileInputStream(filename);
        // read characters until EOF is encountered
        do {
        i = fin.read();
        if(i != -1)  s =s+(char) i+"";
        } while(i != -1);
        fin.close();
        return s;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is from the current working directory.

Comment: @Sambit can you clarify a little bit how did you get into this ? Thank you so much

Comment: The current working directory is not actually a Java concept;  it is a feature of every operating system.  If you were to enter `type test.txt` in a Windows terminal or `cat test.txt` in a Unix terminal, the same rules would apply.

Answer (score 2):

When no absolute paths are defined, the paths are normally relative to the working directory - meaning if you run the application from `/myfolder`, it will be read from `/myfolder/test.txt`.

As such, it is helpful to use standards (like `System.getProperty("user.home")`) as prefix.

Note that defining an absolute path will most likely prevent the application from working System independent. The same goes for using `/` or `\` as path segment separator.

Comment: Thanks, i got a copy of my "test.txt" file in every folder from that path you said (```System.getProperty("user.home")```) to below, but when i run my code it still throws FileNotFoundException. Could you please check if it works on your machine?

Comment: It does - substituting `String filename = "text.txt";` with `String filename = System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "test.txt";` led to File contents being printed on the console.

Comment: I see clearly that your response is perfect, but idk why it still doesn't work for me :/

Comment: Try a simple `System.out.println(filename)` and see if a file at that location exists.
It is very easy to introduce typos when typing manually as opposed to selecting from  a menu.
If all else fails, do the following:
`new FileWriter("myFilename.txt").write("I am a stegosaurus!");`
and then locate the file with the name `myFilename.txt`

Comment: I have done what you said in the last comment, and the text file 'test.txt' already existed there. Idk why it doesn't work yet, it have no sense. But thanks for your help!

Comment: It's always safe to use a slash `/` in java as path segment separator. It works for both, Windows and Linux/Unix. Do not use `\\` to separate the paths - it only works for Windows and you have to escape the backslash in a string. I do not recommend to make heavy use of system properties and File.separator, it just makes your code unreadable. It's OK to say "./files/test.txt". It just works.

Answer (score 1):

You can check your currently user directory with:

```
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

Answer (score 1):

The file name actually is a relative path - it does not contain any drive letter and does not start with `/` or `\`.
It is resolved starting from your current working directory. This directory depends on how you actually start the program.

E.g. if you run java from a command line prompt, then the directory you are currently in is the base directory. If you `cd` to another directory, the program will search for the file there.

If you start the program from your IDE, the default folder for the working directory is the project's base directory. You can change this in the run-configuration, though.

If nothing helps, try printing the directory from your program, e.g.:

```
System.out.println("Current dir: " + new java.io.File( "." ).getCanonicalPath())
```